# Auto orienting image when using delayed job

Tags: ruby-on-rails, imagemagick, paperclip, carrierwave, delayed-job

I have a photo sharing application that allows the user to drag and drop images which are then processed in delayed job and displayed in a gallery. I'm having some problems solving the [problem with orientation on iPhone pictures](http://pleaselistencarefully.com/Why-photo-rotation-is-broken-on-the-iphone-4-and-how-to-fix-it-using-paperclip-on-heroku). I have the following code:

**initializers/auto_orient.rb**

```
module Paperclip
  class AutoOrient < Paperclip::Processor 
    def initialize(file, options = {}, *args)
      @file = file
    end

    def make( *args )
      dst = Tempfile.new([@basename, @format].compact.join("."))
      dst.binmode

      Paperclip.run('convert',"#{File.expand_path(@file.path)} -auto-orient #{File.expand_path(dst.path)}")

      return dst
    end
  end
end
```

**models/picture.rb**

```
class Picture < ActiveRecord::Base

  belongs_to :gallery

  before_create :generate_slug
  after_create :send_to_delayed_job

  validates :slug, :uniqueness => true

  scope :processing, where(:processing => true)

  attr_accessible :image

  has_attached_file :image,
  :styles => {
    :huge => "2048x1536>",
    :small => "800x600>",
    :thumb => "320x240>"
  },
  :processors => [:auto_orient, :thumbnail]

  before_post_process :continue_processing

  ...

  def process
    self.image.reprocess!
    self.processing = false
    self.save(:validations => false)
  end

  private

  def continue_processing
    if self.new_record?
      !self.processing
    end
  end

  def send_to_delayed_job
    Delayed::Job.enqueue ImageProcess.new(self.id), :queue => 'paperclip'
  end
end
```

**models/image_process.rb**

```
class ImageProcess < Struct.new(:picture_id)

  def perform
    picture = Picture.find(self.picture_id)
    picture.process
  end

end
```

If I comment out the lines `after_create :send_to_delayed_job` and `before_post_process` i.e. the processing is done on the spot, the auto-orientation process works. But, when I put it through delayed job, no auto-orientation happens, just the resizing.

Does anyone have any ideas?

**EDIT**

It get's stranger. I moved to Carrierwave and the carrierwave_backgrounder gem. Ignoring background tasks for now, I have the following in my `image_uploader.rb`:

```
def auto_orient
  manipulate! do |img|
    img.auto_orient!
    img
  end
end

version :huge do
  process :auto_orient
  process resize_to_fit: [2048,1536]
end
```

This works. The images are in the correct orientation.

Now, if I add `process_in_background :image` to my `picture.rb` file in accordance with the instructions for carrier wave_backgrounder, auto_orient doesn't work.

I'm now going to try the `store_in_background` method to see if that makes a difference.

Comment: I'm using
`convert ":source -auto-orient :dest", source: "#{File.expand_path(@file.path)}", dest: File.expand_path(dst.path)`

instead of 
`Paperclip.run('convert',"#{File.expand_path(@file.path)} -auto-orient #{File.expand_path(dst.path)}")`

cuz had issues with files with special signs and spaces in names

Answer (score 0):

I noticed you have `attr_accessible` in your Picture model. I have been working with Delayed_Job recently and after many hours of struggling with it I figured out that it has serious issues with `attr_accessible`. There are workarounds, though.

More info is [here](https://groups.google.com/forum/?fromgroups=#!topic/delayed_job/YLauVaMwTAg) (although you can Google for more on the topic)